# Store IPv6 address from the routing table to a linklist (Contiki/Cooja)

Tags: contiki

I want to store the IPv6 address of the just immediate nodes from the routing table in a linklist. So the linklist can be used to send messages to only chosen nodes.

1. I fixed the routing to "storing mode" by explicitly stating to use RPL-Classic in MAKE file.
2. I altered a code to access the routing table every 60 seconds and from the table I am storing the addresses of just immediate nodes (uip_ds6_route_nexthop(route)) in a contiki-defined linklist (list_route).
3. As suggested by an expert, in the code i used Contiki own defined "memb_alloc/free".
4. But when I am trying to print this linklist, it is not printing any IP addresses. It just print the text "Route IPV6" but IP address is not printed.

```
#include "contiki.h"
#include "sys/node-id.h"
#include "sys/log.h"
#include "net/ipv6/uip-ds6-route.h"
#include "net/ipv6/uip-sr.h"
#include "net/mac/tsch/tsch.h"
#include "net/routing/routing.h"
#define LOG_MODULE "App"
#define LOG_LEVEL LOG_LEVEL_DBG
#define DEBUG DEBUG_PRINT
#include "net/ipv6/uip-debug.h"
#include "lib/list.h"
#include "lib/memb.h"

/* List Structure to store IPv6 address from the routing table */
struct list_route {
  struct list_route *next;
  const uip_ipaddr_t ipaddr;
};

LIST(neighb_table);                    // Contiki defined list 
MEMB(route_mem, struct list_route, 5);    //memory block for the list MEMB(name, structure, num);

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
PROCESS(node_process, "RPL Node-Storing Mode");
AUTOSTART_PROCESSES(&node_process);

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
PROCESS_THREAD(node_process, ev, data)
{
  int is_coordinator;

  PROCESS_BEGIN();

/* Initialize the memory for the neighbor table entries. */
  memb_init(&route_mem);

/* Initialize the list used for the neighbor table. */
  list_init(neighb_table);



  is_coordinator = 0;

#if CONTIKI_TARGET_COOJA || CONTIKI_TARGET_Z1
  is_coordinator = (node_id == 1);
#endif

  if(is_coordinator) {
    NETSTACK_ROUTING.root_start();
  }
  NETSTACK_MAC.on();


 
    static struct etimer et;
    /* Print out routing tables every minute */
    etimer_set(&et, CLOCK_SECOND * 60);
    while(1) {
      LOG_INFO("Routing entries: %u\n", uip_ds6_route_num_routes());
    
    if(uip_ds6_route_num_routes()){ 
      uip_ds6_route_t *route = uip_ds6_route_head();
      struct list_route *e;
      while(route) {
        LOG_INFO("Route ");
        LOG_INFO_6ADDR(&route->ipaddr);
        LOG_INFO_("/128 via ");
        LOG_INFO_6ADDR(uip_ds6_route_nexthop(route));
        LOG_INFO_("\n");
    
    /* Removing any previous same entry from the list (to avoid buffer overflow)*/
    for(e = list_head(neighb_table); e != NULL; e = e->next) {
            if(uip_ip6addr_cmp(&e->ipaddr,uip_ds6_route_nexthop(route))) {
         list_remove(neighb_table, e);
         memb_free(&route_mem, e);
        }
        }


    e = memb_alloc(&route_mem);                 // Allocate memory from the route_mem pool
    e->next=NULL;
    uip_ip6addr_copy(&e->ipaddr, uip_ds6_route_nexthop(route));     //Copy IPv6 address
    list_add(neighb_table, e);                                      //Append the structure in the list

    route = uip_ds6_route_next(route);
      }
    /* Print out the list */
    e = list_head(neighb_table);
    while (e != NULL)
            {
    LOG_INFO_("Route IPV6 ");
        LOG_INFO_6ADDR(&e->ipaddr);
    LOG_INFO_("\n");
        e=e->next;
        }
    
    }
      PROCESS_YIELD_UNTIL(etimer_expired(&et));
      etimer_reset(&et);
    
  }
  PROCESS_END();
}
```

**Output for the above code when filter set to "Route" is**

```
00:07.948   ID:1    [WARN: IPv6 Route] No route found
00:07.948   ID:1    [WARN: IPv6 Route] No route found
00:09.838   ID:2    [WARN: IPv6 Route] No route found
00:09.928   ID:4    [WARN: IPv6 Route] No route found
00:11.068   ID:1    [WARN: IPv6 Route] No route found
00:11.068   ID:1    [WARN: IPv6 Route] No route found
00:11.908   ID:1    [WARN: IPv6 Route] No route found
00:11.908   ID:1    [WARN: IPv6 Route] No route found
00:15.298   ID:3    [WARN: IPv6 Route] No route found
00:15.298   ID:3    [WARN: IPv6 Route] No route found
00:15.328   ID:1    [WARN: IPv6 Route] No route found
00:15.328   ID:1    [WARN: IPv6 Route] No route found
01:00.382   ID:1    [INFO: App       ] Route fd00::205:5:5:5/128 via fe80::203:3:3:3
01:00.382   ID:1    [INFO: App       ] Route fd00::203:3:3:3/128 via fe80::203:3:3:3
01:00.382   ID:1    [INFO: App       ] Route fd00::204:4:4:4/128 via fe80::204:4:4:4
01:00.382   ID:1    [INFO: App       ] Route fd00::202:2:2:2/128 via fe80::202:2:2:2
01:00.382   ID:1    Route IPV6 
01:00.382   ID:1    Route IPV6 
01:00.382   ID:1    Route IPV6 
01:00.899   ID:3    [INFO: App       ] Route fd00::205:5:5:5/128 via fe80::205:5:5:5
01:00.899   ID:3    Route IPV6
```

Comment: Which msp430 compiler version you are using? Some versions are quite buggy, in particular the older ones are known to have bugs. I just checked and the code works for me using Contiki-NG Docker.

Comment: if i run 'msp430-gcc --version' i am getting result as 'msp430-gcc (GCC) 4.7.3 20130411 (mspgcc dev 20120911)'. I am also using Contiki-NG Docker, specifically i am staring cooja using following commands: 'contiker', 'cd tools/cooja', 'ant'

Comment: I just re installed the same msp430-gcc version and some how i am able to get the correct output. @kfx thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I believe you have uncovered a bug in Contiki. DIO packets are dropped on some platforms (at least msp430) because of frame filtering. As a workaround, I suggest adding this to `project-conf.h`: #define TSCH_CONF_HW_FRAME_FILTERING 0